# How to compare two text files and find the similarities between then?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

i have loaded both of my files into an array and im trying to compare both of the files to get the comparisons inside the file. However when I run my code I don't receive an output.

This is the contents of both files.
file1

```
tdogicatzhpigu
```

file2

```
dog
pig
cat
rat
fox
cow
```

So when it does a comparison between the words from search1.txt and the words from text1.txt. I want to find the occurence of each word from search1.txt in text1.txt
What I want to eventually output is whether it has been found the index of the location inside the array.
e.g 
"dog". Found, location 1.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream file1("text1.txt");
    if (file1.is_open())
    {
        string myArray[1];

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            file1 >> myArray[i];
```

any further help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, if `file1` fails to open, your program continues to search `file2`.  Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to return/ what you consider to be a similarity? Do you want a tally, so that you'd return 3 in this case? Or just a boolean, that returns true if anything matches?

Comment: Your `myArray` disappears after exiting the `file1` if statement.  Is this intended?

Comment: Are you able to more specifically define what a similarity between two text files means? If one text file is "aaa" and another text file is "bbbaaa" do I have one similarity (they both contain "a"), 9 similarities (each "a" in the first file matches each of 3 "a"s in the second file), or 0 similarities ("aaa" is at index [0,3) in file 1, but at index [3,6) in the second file)

Comment: All the code involving `myArray` seems pointless and irrelevant.

Comment: Somethings awry:  your program is expecting at least 14 lines of text for file 1, but you only show 1 in your post.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the goal is to search the text in `file1` for each word in `file2`.

You can't use equality for the two strings, as they aren't equal.  You'll need to use the `std::string::find` method:

```
std::string target_string;
std::getline(file1, target_string);
std::string keyword;
while (getline(file2, keyword))
{
    const std::string::size_type position = target_string.find(keyword);
    std::cout << "string " << keyword << " ";
    if (position == std::string::npos)
    {
        std::cout << "not found.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "found at position " << position << "\n";
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**
An implemented example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    const std::string   target_string = "tdogicatzhpigu";
    const std::string   key_list[] =
    {
        "dog",
        "pig",
        "cat",
        "rat",
        "fox",
        "cow",
    };

    static const unsigned int key_quantity =
        sizeof(key_list) / sizeof(key_list[0]);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < key_quantity; ++i)
    {
        const std::string::size_type position = target_string.find(key_list[i]);
        std::cout << "string " << key_list[i] << " ";
        if (position == std::string::npos)
        {
            std::cout << "not found.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "found at position " << position << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I run the code, i get the outputs: `string dog found at position 1
string pig found at position 10
string cat found at position 5
string rat not found.
string fox not found.
string cow not found.`

Comment: I used the input string: `"tdogicatzhpigu"`

Comment: Input string is the string in your `file1`.

Comment: See my implemented example.